# azure data factory dataset cleanup

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Does anyone tell me how Azure Data factory datasets are cleaned up (removed, deleted etc). Is there any policy or settings to control it?

From what I can say, all the time series of data sets are left behind intact.

Say, I want to develop an activity which overwrites data daily in the destination folder in Azure Blob or Data Lake storage (for example which is mapped to external table in Azure Datawarehouse and it is a full data extract). How can I achieve this with just copy activity? Shall I add custom .Net activity to do the cleanup no longer needed datasets myself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need a custom activity to delete pipepline output. 
You could have pipeline activities that overwrite the same output but you must be careful to understand how ADF slicing model and activity dependency works, so that anything using the output gets a clear and repeatable set.